# Kivy - Two sliders in a layout

Tags: python, slider, kivy

I am trying to use two sliders in layout. The code is given below. The problem is only the second slider responds to the mouse actions. The first slider (and also the button) does not respond at all to the mouse actions. How to make both sliders responsive?
Thanks in advance

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.button import Button

def Exit(instance):
    print('Exit the screen')
    App.get_running_app().stop()

def MainScreen():
    flt = FloatLayout()

    button = Button(text='Hello Kivy World')
    button.size = (200, 100)
    button.size_hint = (None, None)
    button.pos_hint = {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .2}
    button.bind(on_press=Exit)
    flt.add_widget(button)

    slid1 = Slider()
    slid1.id = 'Slider 01'
    slid1.size_hint_x = .75
    slid1.pos_hint = {'x': .125, 'center_y': .5}
    slid1.value_track = True
    slid1.value_track_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]
    slid1.sensitivity = 'handle'
    flt.add_widget(slid1)

    slid2 = Slider()
    slid2.id = 'Slider 02'
    slid2.size_hint_x = .75
    slid2.pos_hint = {'x': .125, 'center_y': .75}
    slid2.value_track = True
    slid2.value_track_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]
    slid2.sensitivity = 'handle'
    flt.add_widget(slid2)

    return flt

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: the second slider is active if you click at the very bottom of your app. really strange

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `floatlayout` to a `boxlayout` it works.

```
flt = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
```

Comment: Yes, sure it works in the minimal code shown above, thanks,but actually it doesn't work in my original code even after changing the FloatLayout to BoxLayout. I will explore further using your hint

Comment: I think your widgets are overlapping. I would try putting each in a seperate BoxLayout and setting sizes to make sure they do not overlap.

Comment: Yes, having the overall layout as BoxLayout makes both the sliders responsive. It works even in my production code. However, organizing my widgets inside the BoxLayout is a tedious task. Anyway a big thanks for looking at my code